# Importing Client.ovpn Error Message

Tags: 20.04, vpn, openvpn

Afternoon,

I am trying to import client.ovpn file from my openvpn3 server.
i following the direction on these links.
https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/connecting-to-access-server-with-linux/

but i had to install openvpn3 packages first. So i followed the direction
using this link.
https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/OpenVPN3Linux

In the last stage, i couldn't update openvpn3 package because 64 bit arch.
i changed my openvpn3.list

From this:

```
deb  https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal main
```

To:

```
deb [arch=amd64]  https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal main
```

And i am still getting error messages:

```
root@OMN:/home/user# apt update
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal InRelease               
Hit:3 https://swupdate.openvpn.net/community/openvpn3/repos focal InRelease    
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/debian focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

****UPDATE****

I have done some research with google.com and i found out i had to modify
both files to add [arch=amd64]:

```
etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn3.list
etc/apt/sources.list.d/openvpn-as-repo.list
```

when i tried to import my client.ovpn, i get this error message

```
user@user-OMN:~$ openvpn3 config-import --config ${client.ovpn}
bash: ${client.ovpn}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Try the config-import command again but don't wrap "client.ovpn" in the ${}

Comment: @BrianTurek i tried but i get this: `openvpn3 config-import --config $client.ovpn
config-import: ** ERROR ** ERR_PROFILE_GENERIC: cannot open for read: .ovpn`

Comment: @BrianTurek `sudo openvpn3 config-import --config client.ovpn
config-import: ** ERROR ** ERR_PROFILE_GENERIC: cannot open for read: client.ovpn`

Comment: Can you substitute the full path to your client.ovpn file?  So something like `sudo openvpn3 config-import --config /path/to/client.ovpn`

Comment: @BrianTurek `root@OMN:/home# openvpn3 config-import --config /user/Downloads/client.ovpn
config-import: ** ERROR ** ERR_PROFILE_GENERIC: cannot open for read: /user/Downloads/client.ovpn`

Comment: `/user/Downloads/client.ovpn` doesn't look like a normal directory.  Do you mean something like `/home/user/Downloads/client.ovpn`?

Comment: @BrianTurek i think it imported

Comment: `root@OMN:~# openvpn3 config-import --config /home/user/Downloads/client.ovpn
Configuration imported.  Configuration path: /net/openvpn/v3/configuration/20861435x54c7x45b7xa047x279c972048021`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write this up as a solution:

- Adding `[arch=amd64]` into your apt sources limited apt to only looking at the 64-bit repository, avoiding the notice about the i386 repo
- The `${client.ovpn}` is performing variable substitution in your shell which causes it to look for a variable called `client.ovpn`.  You didn't have this variable declared and I don't believe variables with periods in the name are allowed (thus the error about a bad substitution)
- When pointing programs at files using the command-line, you either need to give it the full path to the file (e.g. `/home/user/Downloads/client.ovpn`) or have shell in the directory already (e.g. `cd /home/user/Downloads/ && openvpn3 config-import --config client.ovpn`)